# Blogdown Website post - Hide date and/or title of post

Tags: r, blogdown

I would like to remove the date from a post without having to manually delete from the html from the public folder after running blogdown::build_site().

I have a post called Gallery which has the following yaml header in the Rmarkdown file at the top:

```
---
title: Gallery
date: null
output:
  blogdown::html_page:
    date: null
---
```

This is how it is rendered in the public/gallery/index.html file:

```
<div class="item">
    <h4><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></h4>
    <h5>January 1, 0001</h5>
</div>
```

Anyway to remove/hide it without doing it manually?

I'm using the minimal theme https://github.com/calintat/minimal/

Comment: Will using `date: ""` work?

Comment: No, I tried that as well as date: Null or date: or removing date altogther. The date still appears with the date of January 1, 0001

Answer (score 8):

What you are asking for is not natively packed with the theme. But a simple line of tweak will do.

1. Create folder `layouts/partials/` in your repo(if it does not exist).
2. Copy `themes/minimal/layouts/partials/list-item.html` to `layouts/partials/list-item.html`
3. Change [this line](https://github.com/calintat/minimal/blob/master/layouts/partials/list-item.html#L20):

   ```
   <h5>{{ $.Scratch.Get "subtitle" }}</h5>
   ```

   to

   ```
   {{ if not .Params.hidedate }}<h5>{{ $.Scratch.Get "subtitle" }}</h5>{{ end }}
   ```
4. In the yaml header of your post, add `hidedate: true`, like this:

   ```
   ---
   title: "Creating a New Theme"
   tags: ["go", "golang", "hugo", "themes"]
   hidedate: true
   draft: false
   ---
   ```

This will turn off the date; other normal posts remain unaffected.

---

Comment: Thanks although copying the file to the new folder and updating it didn't work. I was able to get it work by directly adjusting the file in the theme folder itself. I just went ahead and deleted the lines because for this site I never need the date.

Comment: Actually, looks like I did need the date or subtitle for some of the posts. So went back to your option and only difference is I edited the file directly.  Looks good!

Comment: Yes it should work. if you don't need to switch/update theme in the future, your solution is simpler